# Run exe file through Cygwin .error output :Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, cygwin

I am new with cygwin and C programm. I got a tough problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10 
int main()
{
    int nPerson[N]={9,11,23,44,2,4,5,6,7,3};
    int nFloor,nMinFloor,nTargetFloor;
    nTargetFloor = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        nFloor=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            nFloor+=nPerson[j]*(i-j);
        for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
            nFloor+=nPerson[j]*(j-i);
        if(nTargetFloor=-1||nMinFloor>nFloor){
            nTargetFloor=i;
            nMinFloor=nFloor;

        }

    }
    printf("%s,%s",nTargetFloor,nMinFloor);
//  return(nTargetFloor,nMinFloor);

}
```

After I complie the file with `gcc -std=c99  -o code1081 code1801.c`

then I run the .exe file with ./code1081.exe ,the console output the error message "Segmentation fault(core dumped) ".
Thank you for help me figure the error point. Big Thanks

Comment: Ah, and we [close all the typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions), by the way.

Comment: You do one more thing compile the file with `-g` option and then `gdb code1801` .

Comment: you couldn't find the mistake because you don't keep space after `,` and `;` , and `a=b` must be `a = b`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan And another excellent example why code formatting is important. No one ever wants to/can read ugly crap like `if(nTargetFloor=-1||nMinFloor>nFloor){`...

Comment: Yes Andyqee: your code is indented but expressions are not readable easily.

Comment: Iiiiiit's Yet Another `=`[`=`] Bug!

Answer (score 2):

`if(nTargetFloor=-1||nMinFloor>nFloor){`

This line should be

`if(nTargetFloor == -1||nMinFloor>nFloor){`

Comparison should use `==` instead of `=`. A hard to find bug:)

Comment: Even lazy people can leave everything off to a debugger , if they want to :P ....... and this `==` instead of `=` posts are 1 in every 5 on SO